# How can i fix Application' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Application' and 'System.Windows.Forms.Application'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roblox

i tried using "System.Application' "System.Windows.Application"
Code:
pastebin . com LK5F8HpA
i could not say it here

Comment: Probably you have both _using System.Windows_ and _using System.Windows,Forms_ choose one

Answer (score 0):

If there is need for both assemblies in one class, simply preface the specific types with the entire namespace.

So:

```
System.Windows.WhatEverIsNeededHere foo = new System.Windows.WhatEverIsNeededHere();
```

And:

```
System.Windows.Forms bar = new System.Windows.Forms();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to resolve ambiguities like these is by understanding what you are using and why you are using it.
Then use the proper using/importing declaration and or use fully qualified name so that your program can compile and you do not have ambiguity problems.

When you ask a question, Please provide more information about what Framework you are using and what version and what kind of applications you are building...
Form? WPF? Core or full version? etc

In DotNet Namespace: System.Windows.Forms.Application,  Assembly System.Windows.Forms.dll
While in core: Namespace:System.Windows, Assembly:PresentationFramework.dll

Use fully qualified name  to solve this problem quickly.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Msdn link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/namespace-alias-qualifier) you can use namespace alias and '::' operator to fix your issue.

Quick fix

```
using forwinforms = System.Drawing;
using forwpf = System.Windows;

public class Converters
{
    public static forwpf::Point Convert(forwinforms::Point point) => new forwpf::Point(point.X, point.Y);
}
```